# How can I display these images in a 2x2 grid?

Tags: html, css

My goal here is to display 4 images in a 2x2 grid at the center of the page that will have text underneath all of the images. These images will then serve as a link to other pages. However, I am having trouble getting these images to display how I would like them to! Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see relevant code. Thank you!

```css
#main img{
    max-width: 500px; 
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    align-items: center;
    border: 3px lightblue solid;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
    <div id="main">
        <div class="category-1">
          <img src="./images/apples.jpg" alt="Sandwich"/>
          <h3>Candy Apples!</h3>
          <p>Just some random text, lorem ipsum text praesent tincidunt ipsum lipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="category-2">
          <img src="./images/santacookie.jpg" alt="Steak">
          <h3>Christmas Cookies!</h3>
          <p>Once again, some random text to lorem lorem lorem lorem ipsum text praesent tincidunt ipsum lipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="category-3">
          <img src="./images/eastertreats.jpg" alt="Cherries">
          <h3>Easter Treats!</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum text praesent tincidunt ipsum lipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="category-4">
          <img src="/w3images/wine.jpg" alt="Pasta and Wine">
          <h3>Category 4</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum text praesent tincidunt ipsum lipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why not use a table?

Comment: Point the way sir and I will try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed and used the grid properties wrongly.
Try this:

```
#main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

#main img{
    max-width: 500px; 
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px lightblue solid;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. That does it! Thank you friend.